# Significant lineal model (p value) but no significant parameters

Tags: regression-coefficients, model

I´m interested to know if it´s possible (and what it means) to obtain a significant linear model regression (p value=0.008) with coefficients fitted are not significant (p>0.05)?

Comment: You will find extensive discussions of this and related phenomena by searching related keywords that include [collinearity](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=significance+collinearity+regression).

Comment: That's interesting @Dimitriy, but I feel obliged to point out it's the *reverse* situation: the regression itself is not significant even though individual coefficients are "significant."